# Focal length of concave mirror with water

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

I want to find the focal length of mirror in the picture below.

[image: Concave mirror with water.]

I know that beetween air and water the refraction happens, then light passes throuh water with thickness $d$, then it bounces on the surface of concave mirror, passes through water again and at last the final refraction happens beetween water and air.

Here is the matric form of the above problem. And I don't know what does this tell me.

[image]

Comment: This [ABCD Matrix](https://www.rp-photonics.com/abcd_matrix.html) article from the RP Photonics Encyclopedia might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but i have already solved it.